# What's wrong with this implementation of 'Highest product of consecutive elements'

Tags: ruby, max

I am trying to write a method that returns the highest product from adjacent values within an array. Below is my attempt to do so however it fails to return the highest products in some instances, patterns of which I am unclear on and I cannot see why the problems with this code:

```
def adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray)
   inputArray.each_with_index do |value, index|
      if inputArray[index+1]
         products = [] << value * inputArray[index + 1]
         return products.max
      end
   end
end
```

a) Can anyone help me understand what is wrong with the above implementation

b) Can anyone suggest a less verbose and simpler method of achieving the desired.

Here are the fails and passes (*this is from codefights.com, 1st question, 2nd chapter 'Edge of the Ocean'*):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: With what inputs does it fail?

Comment: Updated above @Dragonthoughts, thanks.

Comment: This is a programming site, not an arts site. Please, post your code and the inputs and outputs, not pictures of them.

Comment: You may know that camelCase is not normal in ruby code. I assume you may have no choice in Codefights, with which I am not familiar. But shame on them for doing it that way.

Comment: jbk, I presume Jorg asked you to remove the pics because links tend to be broken. If you enter that as text your question will remain unbroken here until the end of time. Some new to SO show their *code* in a pic (you didn't do that), meaning that all readers who want to run it have to copy it manually.

Comment: (Just in case it isn't crystal clear from the preceding comments, change your inputs and outputs to a textual description and your downvotes will start to disappear)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're returning from the method after calculating only the first product. So all your answers are simply the product of the first two numbers. To fix it, initialize your `products` variable before the loop and put your `return` after the loop.

As for a cleaner implementation, take a look at Enumerable's `each_cons`, which returns consecutive members of an array (for example, `each_cons(2)` returns consecutive pairs). Then you can multiply each pair in one fell swoop via `map` and return the maximum.

```
def adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray)    
  inputArray.each_cons(2).map{|a,b| a*b}.max
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I presume that, for an array `arr`, you want the largest product

```
arr[i] * arr[i+1] * arr[i+2] *...* arr[j-1] * arr[j]
```

where `0 <= i <= j <= arr.size-1`. We can do that in a Ruby-like way using [Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons), as @Mark suggested.

```
def max_adjacent_product(arr)
  n = (1..arr.size).each_with_object({prod: -Float::INFINITY, adj: []}) do |len, best|
    arr.each_cons(len) do |a|
      pr = a.reduce(:*)
      best.replace({prod: pr, adj: a}) if pr > best[:prod]
    end
  end
end

max_adjacent_product [2, -4, 3, -5, -10]
  #=> {:prod=>150, :adj=>[3, -5, -10]}
```

I loop through the number of adjacent elements to consider. In the example, that would be from `1` to `5`. For each number of adjacent elements, `len`, I then loop through each subarray `a` of adjacent elements of `arr` for which `a.size` equals `len`. In the example, for `len = 3`, that would be `[2, -4, 3]`, `[-4, 3, -5]` and `[3, -5, -10]`. For each of those subarrays of adjacent elements I then compute the product of its elements (`-24`, `60` and `150` for the example just given). If a product is greater than the best known product so far I make it the `best` subarray so far. The final value of `best` is returned by the method.